# Erro de compilação Java (Eclipse) usando a classe Scanner, problema de iniciante

Tags: java, eclipse, scanner

Estou começando a estudar Java agora pelo livro "Java como Programar 10 Edª" e estou com tendo dificuldade para compilar esse código do livro no Eclipse ( Segue a imagem do Erro ).

Segue o codigo abaixo

Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer esse código compilar ?

Obs: JDK 9, Java 9, Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2

[image: Erro quando compilo o seguinte código]

```
public class Account {
  private String name;
  private double balance;

  public Account (String name, double balance) {
    this.name = name;

    if (balance > 0.0)
      this.balance = balance;
  }// Fim metodo


  public void deposit (double depositAmount) {
    if (depositAmount > 0.0)
      balance = balance + depositAmount;
  }//fim metod0

  public double getBalance () {
    return balance;
  }//fim get

  public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }//fim set

  public String getName () {
    return name;
  }//fim get
}


public class AccountTest {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Cria os objetos e atribui argumentos para o cosntrutor
        Account account1 = new Account("Jane Gree", 50.00);
        Account account2 = new Account("John Blue", -7.53);

        // Exibe o saldo inicial
        System.out.printf("% balance: $%.2f %n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("% balance: $%.2f  %n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Obtendo a entrada na conta 1
        System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account1: ");
        double depositAmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%n adding %.2f to account1 balance %n%n", depositAmount);
        account1.deposit(depositAmount);

        // exibe os saldos
        System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2 %n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2 %n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());

        // Obtendo a entrada na conta 2
        System.out.print("Enter deposit amount for account2: ");
        depositAmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%nadding %.2f to account2 balance %n%n", depositAmount);
        account2.deposit(depositAmount);
        // exibe os saldos
        System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2 %n", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2 %n%n", account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());
        input.close();

  }

}
```

Comment: O problema está na formatação do seu `System.out` na linha 12 do `AccountTest`. Mude para `System.out.printf("%s balance: $%.2f", account1.getName(), account1.getBalance());`

Comment: Olá, Lucas! Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Sempre que colocar um erro ou mesmo um código na sua pergunta (ou resposta), evite o uso de imagens para isto, pois as próximas pessoas que procurarem pelo mesmo erro no futuro não encontrarão sua pergunta uma vez que o código de erro estará na imagem e não em um texto.

Comment: Outra coisa, como nesse caso existe um indicador de qual linha tem o defeito, quando for colar o código aqui, faça um comentário indicando qual a linha que o indicador acusa. O log ali indica a linha 12, mas qual é a linha 12?

Comment: Olha obrigado pela ajuda, e pelos conselhos na próxima dúvida eu coloco, como aconselhado.
E deu certo era só colocar %s no meu código hahaha